# $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{b+c-a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\leq 3 $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle, prove that
> $$\frac{\sqrt{b+c-a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a-b}}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}+\frac{\sqrt{a+b-c}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}}\leq 3 $$

I got , enough to show
$\sum_{cyc}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{a+b-c}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}}\right)\geq0 $ or show
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{ab}-\sqrt{c(a+b-c)}}{\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b-\sqrt c\right)\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c+\sqrt{a+b-c}\right)}\geq 0.$$

Any help ?

Comment: @CalvinLin the simplification is right ,Raheel, are you aware of generalised schur inequality? if so you are close...

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Ah okay, I see that now.

Comment: This is IMO 2006 Shortlist A5

Comment: You have the official solution [here (page $15$)](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2006SL.pdf). It has also been posted here, in MSE; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372857/sum-cyclic-frac-sqrtbc-a-sqrtb-sqrtc-sqrta-leq-3?noredirect=1) for instance. You will also find many different posts on aops, such as [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h149013p842206), or [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h130812) and many more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{cyclic}\frac{\sqrt{b+c-a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\leq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372857/sum-cyclic-frac-sqrtbc-a-sqrtb-sqrtc-sqrta-leq-3)