# Can anyone make the easier solution with Schur inequality? Thank you!

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are the lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
$\frac{\sqrt{a+b-c}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c-a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a-b}}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}\leq 3$

I tried Schur inequality:

It can be written as:

$\sum_{cyc}^{}\sqrt{a+b-c}(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})\leq 3\prod _{cyc}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})$ which is very complicated and opposite from the one I knew is:$xyz\geq (x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y),\forall x,y,z\geq 0$

Also I do the another idea: Suppose: $a+b+c=3$ so the inequality can be written as: $\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{\sqrt{3-2c}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}}\leq 3$

but this step doesn't make the denominators easier and it still stuck here :()

Can anyone make the easier solution with Schur inequality? Thank you!

Comment: It's easy SOS. Are you sure that you want a solution by Schur only? This inequality we can write in the Schur's form. Maybe do you mean this?

Comment: Yes because I had this problem from Schur lesson:D Thanks a lot for your schur sol!

Comment: The solution by using of the Schur's form see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372857/